# How to create an abstract base class (generally a parent class) that requires its children to have a specific method which sets a specific property?

Tags: python, class, abstract-class, parent-child

I want to define an abstract base class, called ParentClass. I want every child class of ParentClass to have a method called "fit" that defines a property "required". If someone tries to create a child class which does not have the "required" property within its fit method, I want an error to be created when the object's fit method is called. I am having trouble doing this.

The context is that I want to create a Parent class, abstract or otherwise, that requires its children to behave in a certain way and have certain properties so that I can trust them to behave in certain ways no matter who is creating children classes. I have found similar questions, but nothing precisely like what I am asking.

My naive attempt was something like the following:

```
class ParentClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def fit(self):
        self.required = True
    
    
    
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self):
        self.required = True


class ChildClass2(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self):
        self.not_essential = True
```

This doesn't work, but if possible I would like to refactor `ParentClass` in such a way that if someone runs:

```
>> b = ChildClass()
>> b.fit()
```

everything works fine, but if someone tries to run

```
>> b2 = ChildClass2()
>> b2.fit()
```

an error is thrown because the `fit` method of ChildClass2 doesn't define "required".

Is this possible in Python?

A related question is whether there is a better way to think about structuring my problem. Perhaps there is a better paradigm to achieve what I want? I understand that I can force child classes to have certain methods defined. A clunky way to achieve what I want is to have every property I want to be defined to be returned by a required method, but this feels very clunky, particularly if the number of properties I want to enforce as part of a standard becomes rather large.

Comment: Instance attributes defined in places other than `__init__` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: It's not really clear to me how you intend `self.required` to be used. I suppose you could turn it into a property in the ABC, with a getter that raises a `NotImplementedError` if child classes don't implement that property? This seems like a weird use-case that might benefit from a more concrete example.

Comment: The particular example I have in mind is that I want to define various statistical procedures, each of which has a "fit" method. I also want to ensure that the fit method is defining certain properties, like "residuals", "parameters", etc, i.e. properties of the fit. I want to ensure that all child classes have a similar structure in this regard.

Comment: I'd suggest a `Fit` class. As far as I know there's no way you'd be able to inspect each child's implementation to ensure they define certain properties, and as I said in my first comment, defining properties outside `__init__` is considered an anti-pattern.